# Django Forms: Set form element value from template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have Django models as follow:

```
-------------------------
| Form
-------------------------
id | author | text | ...

--------------------------------
| Comment
---------------------------------
id | author | text | form_id | ...
```

The main template has a list of all the posts. I'd like to add the possibility to comment a post. For the moment, I added a Comment form at the end of each post. I need to set the form_id for each Comment form so when a POST method is requested, the view is able to add a new row in the comment table.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code to create those models? If so, please post. To be honest, it's much better if you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you do.

Comment: It sounds like you need a comment model with a foreign key to the Form model.  This would allow multiple comments for any Form entry, or none at all.  Try going thru the django tutorial first